# Replace spaces with underscores in a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

In a WordPress website I want to replace spaces with underscores in the values of a custom field named `mycustomfield` and print it.

Here is the code to print a custom field:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'mycustomfield', true);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

How do I edit that code?

Here is the final result:

A random value of the custom field `mycustomfield` when printed, will be "Las_vegas" instead of "Las Vegas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$field_value = get_post_meta($postid, 'mycustomfield', true);
echo str_replace('_', ' ', $field_value);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: 1.why do you create another var `$field_value`, just for unnecessary memory allocation

Comment: 2. the search pattern is for blank space not the other way around

Comment: Hey 0x13a, you are right, the search pattern is for blank spaces, but I think that the author has made a mistake. 
Regarding the additional variable, I make it just for readability. 
We can make a function without variables, it it will be hard when someone make edits on it.

Comment: doesn't matter dude, i just wanted to point it out, up to you for the variables

Answer (score 2):

use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) php function

```
echo str_replace(' ','_', get_post_meta($postid, 'mycustomfield', true));
```